# Islamic Verse written on paper inside a islamic case necklace?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, shirk, verses, makruh

[image]

Assalaam Alaiqum wa Rehmat Allah.

May Allah SWT have mercy on all of us

I got this necklace from my grandma. Let me summon up the story real quick. My moms sides family is Turkish and as you know the “nazzar” eye which claims to protect you from the evil-eye is Shirk. If I ever got a nazzar eye as a gift I wouldn't have it myself on because I would have known is Shirk.

I got this as a gift, she said that she gotten this from Turkiye (don’t know where) and it is a Quran Verse written on a paper rolled up inside this little box or cage, I don’t know the name sorry.

Here’s my questions. Can I believe in it to protect me or just having it on? Is it Shirk or any makrooh or a sin to wear it around my neck? If I don’t believe in it and only having it on, is it allowed/acceptable? I’m male so am I even allowed to wear it?

I heard that some (fake) sheikhs that give them out for free but there are of names Shaytan written instead. They may even be sold outside from shops.

Jazakallah for Reading and May Allah keep us guided to the straight path Amin.
Please Write Back

Comment: Sort of, but I can't open it without breaking it and checking to see if there are any weird numbers or symbols that may be Shaytan language or name. Like again, I got this as a gift and it was highly valued so breaking it means I guess no fixing it back? I guess it's better than nothing to check and then commit Shirk without knowing, right?

Comment: Right, however I am pretty sure it can be open from the bottom like a lid.

Comment: It’s completely sealed. Doesn’t work to open it up with nails or drag it from the side. Complete sealed, though there is a number underneath that says “925”

Answer (score 0):

It is permissible to wear an amulet for protection against black magic or for healing only if they have the name or attributes of Allah written on them, they are in Arabic, they do not contain anything that is against Islamic teachings, and the user does not believe that the words have power in themselves but that this is done by the grace of Allah. Normally, it is better to supplicate to Allah using duas which have been taught to us in the Qur’an or by the Prophet. If there is a legitimate fear that someone will think the amulet itself is effective, as many people do, then they should not wear them.

[ref](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/136418/is-it-permissible-in-islam-to-wear-taweez-or-amulets-for-protection/)

The thing you have is known as the amulet of Imam Javad and has many properties. It is one of the best Amulet. please search "Imam Javad's amulet" to get more info.